# iOS7 crashing - [__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects

Tags: ios, crash, ios7

Going through my iOS6 app and trying to fix everything for iOS7. Throughout my app I'm getting the error:

```
-[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]
```

Here is the stack trace from this code:

```
NSString *shareString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"I ... %@", self.booking.venue.name];
NSArray *activityItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:shareString, nil];
UIActivityViewController *activityViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc]     initWithActivityItems:activityItems applicationActivities:nil];
[self presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion:nil];

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]'
*** First throw call stack:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x03bc45e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x032d38b6 objc_exception_throw + 44
2   CoreFoundation                      0x03b8a536 -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:] + 390
3   CoreFoundation                      0x03bb8029 +[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:forKeys:count:] + 73
4   UIKit                               0x0141eea4 -[UIButton _intrinsicSizeWithinSize:] + 1255
5   UIKit                               0x017ee81d -[UIView(UIConstraintBasedLayout) intrinsicContentSize] + 51
6   UIKit                               0x017eeebf -[UIView(UIConstraintBasedLayout) _generateContentSizeConstraints] + 36
7   UIKit                               0x017eeb50 -[UIView(UIConstraintBasedLayout) _updateContentSizeConstraints] + 511
8   UIKit                               0x017f4e8f -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) updateConstraints] + 110
9   UIKit                               0x0141dab7 -[UIButton updateConstraints] + 54
10  UIKit                               0x017f4728 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _internalUpdateConstraintsIfNeededAccumulatingViewsNeedingSecondPass:] + 239
11  UIKit                               0x017f48a6 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsIfNeededAccumulatingViewsNeedingSecondPass:] + 122
12  UIKit                               0x017f4827 __UIViewRecursionHelper + 40
13  CoreFoundation                      0x03b65dc9 CFArrayApplyFunction + 57
14  UIKit                               0x017f46cc -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _internalUpdateConstraintsIfNeededAccumulatingViewsNeedingSecondPass:] + 147
15  UIKit                               0x017f48a6 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsIfNeededAccumulatingViewsNeedingSecondPass:] + 122
16  UIKit                               0x017f4827 __UIViewRecursionHelper + 40
17  CoreFoundation                      0x03b65dc9 CFArrayApplyFunction + 57
18  UIKit                               0x017f46cc -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _internalUpdateConstraintsIfNeededAccumulatingViewsNeedingSecondPass:] + 147
19  UIKit                               0x017f48a6 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsIfNeededAccumulatingViewsNeedingSecondPass:] + 122
20  UIKit                               0x017f4827 __UIViewRecursionHelper + 40
21  CoreFoundation                      0x03b65dc9 CFArrayApplyFunction + 57
22  UIKit                               0x017f46cc -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _internalUpdateConstraintsIfNeededAccumulatingViewsNeedingSecondPass:] + 147
23  UIKit                               0x017f48a6 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsIfNeededAccumulatingViewsNeedingSecondPass:] + 122
24  UIKit                               0x017f4827 __UIViewRecursionHelper + 40
25  CoreFoundation                      0x03b65dc9 CFArrayApplyFunction + 57
26  UIKit                               0x017f46cc -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _internalUpdateConstraintsIfNeededAccumulatingViewsNeedingSecondPass:] + 147
27  UIKit                               0x017f48a6 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsIfNeededAccumulatingViewsNeedingSecondPass:] + 122
28  UIKit                               0x017e8f48 __62-[UIWindow(UIConstraintBasedLayout) updateConstraintsIfNeeded]_block_invoke + 43
29  Foundation                          0x02e7a3ec -[NSISEngine withBehaviors:performModifications:] + 107
30  Foundation                          0x02d0a145 -[NSISEngine withAutomaticOptimizationDisabled:] + 48
31  UIKit                               0x017e8c60 -[UIWindow(UIConstraintBasedLayout) updateConstraintsIfNeeded] + 225
32  UIKit                               0x017f4f06 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsAtWindowLevelIfNeeded] + 85
33  UIKit                               0x011ed6ef -[UIView(Hierarchy) layoutBelowIfNeeded] + 348
34  UIKit                               0x018a3def -[_UIBackdropContentView backdropView:recursivelyUpdateMaskViewsForView:] + 56
35  UIKit                               0x018a4240 -[_UIBackdropContentView didMoveToWindow] + 273
36  UIKit                               0x011f5be7 -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 1689
37  UIKit                               0x011f5847 -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 761
38  UIKit                               0x011f5847 -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 761
39  UIKit                               0x011f5847 -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 761
40  UIKit                               0x011f5847 -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 761
41  UIKit                               0x011ed070 __45-[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:]_block_invoke + 162
42  UIKit                               0x011ecef8 -[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:] + 260
43  UIKit                               0x011f8031 -[UIView(Internal) _addSubview:positioned:relativeTo:] + 1847
44  UIKit                               0x011eb521 -[UIView(Hierarchy) addSubview:] + 56
45  UIKit                               0x012861f8 -[UITransitionView transition:fromView:toView:removeFromView:] + 1205
46  UIKit                               0x018add65 -[UIViewControllerBuiltinTransitionViewAnimator animateTransition:] + 463
47  UIKit                               0x0153a37d __101-[UIWindowController transition:fromViewController:toViewController:target:didEndSelector:animation:]_block_invoke_2 + 1577
48  UIKit                               0x011acd33 ___afterCACommitHandler_block_invoke + 15
49  UIKit                               0x011accde _applyBlockToCFArrayCopiedToStack + 403
50  UIKit                               0x011acb0a _afterCACommitHandler + 532
51  CoreFoundation                      0x03b8c53e __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 30
52  CoreFoundation                      0x03b8c48f __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 399
53  CoreFoundation                      0x03b6a3b4 __CFRunLoopRun + 1076
54  CoreFoundation                      0x03b69b33 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
55  CoreFoundation                      0x03b6994b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
56  GraphicsServices                    0x04fbb9d7 GSEventRunModal + 192
57  GraphicsServices                    0x04fbb7fe GSEventRun + 104
58  UIKit                               0x0119094b UIApplicationMain + 1225
59  BottlesTonight                      0x000030ad main + 141
60  libdyld.dylib                       0x037b8725 start + 0
)


libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

This code still works perfectly on iOS6, and I don't see anything wrong with it. It occurs when clicking a UIButton, this also occurs when clicking Card.io to allow users to enter card information. Prior to building my app on iOS7 but running the iOS6 app on iOS7 betas I still recieved this error but in more places. Now that I built it for iOS7 a few of the places cleared up themselves but these ones still remain. Any help would be greatly appreciated, this is all that remains prior to submitting for iOS7.

Comment: The stacktrace points to a problem with laying out a `UIButton`.

Comment: I don't believe I did anything wrong elsewhere. There is a normal UIButton connected to IBAction. I've commented out those 4 lines of code and put in log statement and it works just fine so its definitely not how the button is hooked up, and like I said this works perfect in iOS6.

I'm leaning more towards a bug in iOS7. I'm not using auto layout on this particular view so the auto layout info in the stack trace has to be coming from the UIActivityViewController, leading to the crash.

Comment: check your `activityItems` array is nil.

Comment: No it's not nil, and per apples docs ActivityItems can be nil. All four lines of code above can run without it crashing, after it leaves my IBAction method it crashes.

Comment: I can run this same code in another project that was built on iOS7 and it does not crash... However, on the app that does not crash, storyboards and autolayout are both being used.

Comment: As the error message, you are trying to create NSDictionary with nil value. You will need to check on each data if its nil or not.

Comment: I'm using an NSString which is non nil, and an array to hold the string, also not nil. Someone on apples dev forum is experience the same exact problem, I don't believe it's something I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Any success with this problem so far? I've started having the same problem out of a sudden on the same iOS 7 that I've been developing this code. :-/

Comment: Probably the problem is that `self` can't indeed present the `UIActivityViewController`. Check that.

Comment: self cant present the UIActivityView?? I've always used it in the past, what else should present it?

Answer (score 1):

Report this as a bug to Apple: [bugreport.apple.com](http://bugreport.apple.com/). Unless there's something very wrong with your usage of layout constraints, it's a bug in Apple's code.

Comment: I have the same error and i don't even use layout constraints

Comment: I reported it a long time ago and never heard anything from them. Big pain in the ass. And I'm not using autolayout either for this particular app.