# UIImagePickerController as Camera mode crashes on ios 7?

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uiimagepickercontroller

These 4 lines causes the app to crash. If i change to `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary` as source type it works like a charm. It has nothing to do with my current app. Create a new project and added these 4 lines to a UIButton and it still crashes.

```
UIImagePickerController* picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
[self addChildViewController:picker];
[self.view addSubview:picker.view];
```

I've also tried

```
[self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:^{}];
```

and

```
popController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:picker];
[popController presentPopoverFromRect:button.bounds inView:button permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

It will all cause this crash:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary
>   initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from
>   objects[0]'
>   *** First throw call stack: (0x2e17af53 0x388f06af 0x2e0b923b 0x2e0b9003 0x30961f39 0x30961ba1 0x308fa1b7 0x346f5e9b 0x308ec023
>   0x3057524b 0x30570a5b 0x305708ed 0x305702ff 0x3057010f 0x308e4343
>   0x2e1461d5 0x2e143b79 0x2e143ebb 0x2e0aece7 0x2e0aeacb 0x32d89283
>   0x30950a41 0x18135 0x38df8ab7) libc++abi.dylib: terminating with
>   uncaught exception of type NSException

Running iOS 7.0.2 on iPad 2.

Answer (score 0):

```
UIImagePickerController* picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
[self addChildViewController:picker];
[self.view addSubview:picker.view];
```

I have tested this on device and it works Very well looks that you have not checked properly put the brake point and check properly that on which line your app crashes

Comment: It's when the view have been added to subview and when it draws the view it crashes. I created a new project 100% scratch and got it to work, but on another project i created 2 days ago that only has 1 test class (NSObject), the camera crashes. Tried with/without Auto layout and with/without Storyboard. Also tried different build targets. it still crashes. Sounds like a iOS 7 bug, some other guy had same problem but it was with a UIButton http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18862411/ios7-crashing-nsplaceholderdictionary-initwithobjects.